# Can user_register output the password?

Tags: hooks, password, user-registration

I'm trying to output the password of a newly created user in plain text using the user_register hook as explained [in this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/66580/38991).  However, upon doing a var_dump of $_POST, I don't see any password output.  Can user_register actually do this?

If not, might you have any ideas on a hook that would do this for a new user?

Thanks for any insight!

**Edit: Below is the code that I'm using, along with the var_dump**
The code that I'm using for the password is from [this accepted answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/66580/38991).

```
add_action('user_register', 'registration_save');

function registration_save($user_id){
    global $wpdb;
    echo "user saved";
    ob_start();
    var_dump($_POST);
    $result = ob_get_clean();
    echo file_put_contents("file_put_test.txt","Hello World".$result."Password: ".$_POST['pass1']);
    $result = $wpdb->query($wpdb->prepare("REPLACE INTO test
                                          (user,newpass)
                                          values(%s,%s)",
                                          array(
                                              $_POST['username'],
                                              $_POST['pass1']
                                            )
    ));
```

Comment: Please, show the code you're using. And check the guide [ask].

Comment: @brasofilo Thanks for the response; I've added the code to the question above.  It seems not to output either of the variables to the table listed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an action hook in `/wp-admin/includes/user.php` to check if both password fields match:

```
add_action( 'check_passwords', function( $user, $pass1, $pass2 ) 
{
    var_dump($pass1);
    die();
}, 10, 3 );
```

Comment: Thanks that was quite helpful!  I also ended up needing a a way to access the randomly generated passwords when a user creates a new account.  I posted that answer as well.  This worked for all other cases though.

Comment: Nice addition. Duly noted ;)

Answer (score 1):

Found a solution to the randomly generated passwords.  Since I was using a randomly generated password for new users I needed to implement the random_password hook.  I got the idea from [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/93956/38991).  See below for how I implemented it:

```
add_filter('random_password', 'random_pass_save');
function random_pass_save($pass){
    echo file_put_contents("random_pass_save.txt", "Hello world, here's my saved random pass ".$pass);
    return $pass;
}
```

One thing that sort of tripped me up when I first used it was that, unless you put the return statement on the bottom, your email won't send and the password won't work.  So, just a heads up.

Comment: All `add_filter`s have to return something, unlike `add_action`s